# Django 404 on trailing slash

Tags: python, django

When I use the following urlconf:

```
url(
    r'^titles/(?P<order_item_id>\d+)/localized$',
    'metadataorder.title.views.localized_metadata',
    name='localized_metadata',
    ),
```

it works. However if I use the trailing slash (which **all** my other urls use), it 404s.

```
url(
    r'^titles/(?P<order_item_id>\d+)/localized/$',
    'metadataorder.title.views.localized_metadata',
    name='localized_metadata',
    ),
```

Why is this occuring and what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with a naming collision. I changed the url to:

```
r'titles/(?P<order_item_id>\d+)/metadata/localized/$',
```

and it worked.

Comment: You should consider making the trailing slash optional (`.../?$`).

Comment: @NiklasR: you're right, but this should be achieved with [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).